# How to disable push notification and in-app message when user logs out?

Tags: marketing-cloud, push-notification

We used MarketingCloudSDK for our Flutter app, and we created a plugin supporting the push notification and in-app messaging. [sfmc_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/sfmc_plugin)

After user logs in, we set the **userId as the contactKey value**, and then the user will be able to receiving the push notification and in-app message. However, when user logs out, we found the user will still receive the push notifications and in-app messages.

We tried to find a solution on the documentation but failed.

So, please suggest that where we can find the solution or how we can disable the **push notification** and **in-app message** after user logs out for that specific device?

**SDK Specifications:**

iOS: v7.6

Android: v8.0

Answer (score 1):

A common practice involves 2 things:

1. Create an anonymous ID, like a GUID, when your application is first launched (or after your next update) and hold on to that ID to be used as a logged-out or anonymous user state. When your user logs out, set the `Contact Key` to this GUID, and, obviously, when they log in set the `Contact Key` to their "real" ID.
2. In Android you have a few options for disabling notifications. Each of the discrete types of notifications can be disabled individually on their respective managers, or you can disable notifications system-wide in the `Notification Manager` class. Those effectively 'hide' the notification from the user, but they are still sent/received on the device. You can also `disable push` which will opt the user out at the server level and avoid push messages from being delivered. When the user logs in, you'd call `enable push` to re-opt them into receiving notifications. Finally, as a safety-valve you can use the `should show notification` interface to apply your own business logic to the display of notifications. You might, for instance, get the SDK's value for `contact key` and if it is equal to your anonymous GUID you setup then return `false` to suppress messages. `IOS` has most of these options, but lacks the discrete controls per-message type.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed suggestions!